Does the woman posing by an "Entering Salem" sign in Agatha All Along's credits reference another show?
The closing credits of the 2024 MCU TV series Agatha All Along feature a clip of a woman in a witch costume posing in front of an "Entering Salem" sign.

The credits include various references to witches and witchcraft-related scenes from different media. Among the references I've recognized are the Bewitched intro, Nancy Downs from The Craft, Lisa Simpson in her witch costume from The Simpsons, and the Evil Queen disguised as a crone from Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs.
I'm uncertain about the origin of the "Entering Salem" clip, though. I'm wondering if this particular scene is also sourced from an existing TV show or movie. Can anyone identify what this might be referencing?




That's the actual sign outside of Salem, MA. https://www.flickr.com/photos/danielmennerich/9880636996. I don't think it's a show reference, I think it's a "people pose in witch outfits near this sign" reference.

@Valorum However, that does bring up the issue of fair use if the production company scraped that particular segment off the internet.  Plus it seems out of character that 4 out of 5 clips are from well known TV shows, but the 5th one is just some random person.

@PeterM - I'm guessing they did some location shooting in Salem and said 'witch' is a production staffer
